# The argument type 'void Function(String?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(Object?)?'

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

```
DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                              Colors.redAccent,
                              Colors.blueAccent,
                              Colors.purpleAccent
                              //add more colors
                            ]),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.57), //shadow for button
                              blurRadius: 5) //blur radius of shadow
                        ]
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:30, right:30),
                        child:DropdownButton(
                          value: departure,
                          onChanged: (String? val) {
                            setState(() {
                              departure = val!;
                            });
                          },
                          items: listItem.map((valueItem){
                           return DropdownMenuItem(
                              value: valueItem,
                             child: Text(valeItem),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          isExpanded: true, //make true to take width of parent widget
                          underline: Container(), //empty line
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                          dropdownColor: Colors.green,
                          iconEnabledColor: Colors.white, //Icon color
                        )
                    )
                ),
```

and those errors

> Couldn't infer type parameter 'T'.
> Tried to infer 'Object' for 'T' which doesn't work:
> Parameter 'onChanged' declared as     'void Function(T?)?'
> but argument is 'void Function(String?)'.
> The type 'Object' was inferred from:
> Parameter 'value' declared as     'T?'
> but argument is 'String'.
> Parameter 'items' declared as     'List<DropdownMenuItem<T>>?'
> but argument is 'List<DropdownMenuItem<Object>>'.
> Consider passing explicit type argument(s) to the generic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the dataType on `DropdownButton` for this case

```dart
child:DropdownButton<String?>(
  value: departure,
  onChanged: (String? val) {
    setState(() {
     departure = val!;// better do null check or make departure nullable
       });
    },
  items: listItem.map((valueItem){
     return DropdownMenuItem<String?>(
         value: valueItem,
         child: Text(valeItem??"NUll"),
        );
      }).toList(),
```